# How to read file from ZIP archive

Tags: java, zip

I am facing a problem where i need to convery the zipentry into a file.

What happens is that I have a zip file full of csv files. I need to unzip the file and extract out the csv files and read it using a Scanner() which takes in only a file (type) and not a zipentry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Scanner` class also accepts `InputStream` in one of [its constructors](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.InputStream)). Once you have `ZipEntry` (you obtain it from `ZipFile`), you can use it in [`myZipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getInputStream(java.util.zip.ZipEntry)) method to get `InputStream` that you can pass to `Scanner`.

Comment: Unable... sc = new Scanner(ZipFile.getInputStream(entry)); the error given to me was non-static method "ZipFile.getInputStream(entry)); " cannot be cannot be reference from a static context

Comment: @Roy: You should use your ZipFile instance instead, i.e. `myZipFile.getInputStream(entry)`. I thought that open ZIP file with something like: `ZipFile myZipFile = new ZipFile("myfile.zip");`, then you get entry either from `myZipFile.entries()` method, or from `ZipEntry entry = myZipFile.getEntry(...)`, and then you use this entry for opening input stream: `myZipFile.getInputStream(entry)`.